# IntelliJ highlight usages of element at caret for inherited variable

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

I'm running IntelliJ 10.5 and have "Highlight usages of element at caret" enabled. When a variable is selected, it highlights all occurrences within the current file. This works for the most part, but seems to be broken for inherited class variables. Example:

```
// BaseClass.groovy
class BaseClass {
    String foo
}

// SubClass.groovy
class SubClass extends BaseClass {
    String bar
    def someMethod() {
        foo = 'foo'
        bar = 'bar'
    }
    def someOtherMethod() {
        foo = null
        bar = null
    }
}
```

When editing `SubClass.groovy`, selecting `bar` will highlight all `bar` instances. But selecting `foo` doesn't.

Is there someway to configure/enable this behavior or is this an IntelliJ limitation?

**Follow-up**: I tested with Java and highlighting works correctly with inherited variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. Please try IDEA 11, your example works fine for me there.